# how to insert text from multiple smaller files into various locations of a master file?

Tags: linux, shell, text, nested

I'm learning to use ubuntu shell to compile academic notes into a longer document. Say If I have a master file document.txt where I have a table of contents, and I want to insert texts from various chapters (each contained in its own file), how would you do it?

i.e. say I have a directory called "article". in it, I have document.txt chap1.txt chap2.txt chap3.txt

and inside document.txt,

I have "text" here
I want to insert chap1.txt here
I have other "text" here
I want to insert chap2.txt here
etc

How do you do it.
I'm just a beginner. A easy to understand method is best.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking about how to get started with TeX/LaTeX?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it; one of the easiest would be with Perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
while (s/(.*?)"text"//)         # seek&delete up to "text", memorize part before
{
    print $1;                   # output part of line before the matched "text"
    open IN, "chap".++$i.".txt";# open the next chap$i.txt file
    print <IN>;                 # output the entire chapter
    close IN
}
```

If this script is called with `document.txt` as an argument, it outputs the document with the inserted chapters to standard output, which you could redirect to another file.